# Is 'empty chair', when used as a verb, literal or metaphorical?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

The latest verb to have become all the rage in Britain is ***to empty chair***.

It arises from the failure of the political parties, so far, to reach agreement with the broadcasters on the structure of the political TV debates, which will precede the General Election on 7th May.

The Prime Minister has made an offer to participate in one debate only, together with the leaders of at least six other parties. The main Opposition want there to be more debates and especially 'head-to-head' debates between the PM and the Leader of the Opposition.

There exists a vague threat which politicians are playing upon, that if Mr Cameron does not attend the debates, that he will be ***empty-chaired***.

Does this mean that they will actually provide a chair for him to sit on and leave it empty during the course of the debates, thereby drawing attention to the fact that he has not chosen to participate. Or is the term ***empty chair*** being used metaphorically?

Has the verb  ***to empty chair*** been used elsewhere, e.g. in the USA, in such circumstances?

Comment: I've never heard this phrase before. I would have thought that *to empty chair* someone is the same as *to fire* someone (as in, to remove them from their chair). It sounds like the usage here could instead be expanded by *able to defend himself as well as an empty chair* or, more concretely, *unable to defend himself*. In any case, I really doubt that they'll physically have an empty chair there, so this points towards metaphor.

Comment: Do you have a specific usage in context?

Comment: To ' empty chair' :http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/general-election-2015/11365495/Party-leader-TV-debates-Broadcasters-threaten-to-empty-chair-David-Cameron.html

Comment: Have you googled it? It looks like Josh did.

Comment: @Gerger - that is the expression WS2  is referring to (I guess) ..sounds like a journalistic catch-phrase .

Comment: @IanMacDonald  The verb ***to chair*** has existed for a long time. I just looked up the famous cartoon by William Hogarth (1755) ***Chairing the Member***. That was all about the practice of putting the successful candidate in a chair and carrying him around town, after the election. It would be wonderful if some cartoonist would produce something along the lines of Hogarth depicting an ***empty chair***. Sometimes I mourn the passing of Giles. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humours_of_an_Election See final image.

Comment: It sounds very much like a metaphorical use. While they could place an empty chair on the stage of the debate, it doesn't seem necessary to understanding the meaning.

Comment: I found [*as a professional boxer, I was **flat-footed** inside the boxing ring, which was unusual for me*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+was+flat-footed+inside%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), which I'm quite happy to accept as a short form of the more well-known *I was **caught** flat-footed*.  There's not really a "verb" *to flat-foot*, any more than there is a verb *to empty-chair*. But it's not necessary to explicitly specify the verb *([unexpectedly] **caught** with one's feet flat on the ground, [insultingly] **represented** by an empty chair on the podium)*.

Comment: BBC TV has a long-running comedy/news program called 'Have I Got News for You', with a panel of politicians, actors, comedians and other celebs.  MP Roy Hattersley was booked twice, failed to appear, and was replaced by another guest.  Then, in 1993, he did it again, and was 'empty-chaired'.  On the desk in front of his empty chair, they put a tub of lard.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, it is quite common for the past participle to be used adjectivally as in your example (where it is not even necessary to insert the word **caught**), but in this instance the phrase empty chair is clearly activated in a verbal syntax: ***"broadcasters will 'empty chair' leaders who refuse to take part***." The use of apostrophes seems to throw it toward a metaphorical interpretation. Even if they placed an empty chair on the stage, one could interpret the verbal expression as metaphorical since the physical empty chair represents something else: his refusal to participate.

Comment: @ScottM: The first use I can find was [the BBC studying their navel some years back](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/legacy/theeditors/2007/04/empty_chairs.html), where at 01:59 PM on 17 Apr 2007 in the associated discussion, user James commented using the explicitly "verb-derived" form ***empty-chairing***. But it's worth noting the 11 other references to ***empty*** were all *noun* usages. And particularly worth noting that "James" saw fit to put his then-slightly-innovative usage in "scare quotes". But today, because of political circumstances, it's become a commonplace term in all functions.

Comment: Never heard it used as a verb, but an empty chair has literally been used on several notable occasions to represent someone who was not there.  It makes good TV for about 30 seconds, after which it gets trite quite quickly.

Comment: @HotLicks But if it were the Presidential debates and the person failing to occupy the empty chair were the incumbent President, I guess it would be a bit more than 'trite', wouldn't it? For that is the sort of thing we would be talking about here. The Prime Minister's chair would be empty!

Comment: @WS2 - The visual effect of the empty chair loses it's effect rather quickly.  This is separate from the issue of the individual being a "no show".

Comment: @HotLicks I have been at a dinner tonight, and it was suggested by one of the group present, that rather than leave his chair empty, it might be an idea to borrow his wax dummy from Madame Tussauds, and put it in the seat.

Comment: It is worth noting that there are several scenarios where an empty chair is used in less public/political situations.  Eg, some families would leave a chair empty at the dinner table representing a family member away in military service.

Comment: The overwhelming usage of the expression "empty chair" seems to be a counseling technique, especially grief counseling. The opponents could loose credibility by "empty chairing" an incumbent, if he convinces folks that the entire arrangement fell below the dignity of his office.

Answer (score 2):

From the link Josh61 provided above [Party leader TV debates: Broadcasters threaten to 'empty chair' David Cameron](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/general-election-2015/11365495/Party-leader-TV-debates-Broadcasters-threaten-to-empty-chair-David-Cameron.html) the phrase to 'empty chair' is literal not metaphorical, i.e " they will actually provide a chair for him to sit on and leave it empty during the course of the debates, thereby drawing attention to the fact that he has not chosen to participate."

The practice may be new to UK but not new to other parts of the world though not associate with political debates.It is a political gesture or statement usually employed to embarrass the opponents.For example, during his life when the Israeli government refused to allow [Arafat](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/israel/1366340/Empty-chair-protest-as-Israelis-ban-Arafat-from-Bethlehem-special-Mass.html) to attend Christmas Eve special mass at Bethlehem an empty chair was provided and left empty.

The empty chair is not a new practice actually.It originated with Elijah's (empty) chair, a practice that go back to Babylon Talmud time circa  200 CE (AC) (my Jewish cousins may correct me in this); Wikipedia:

At Jewish circumcision ceremonies, a chair is set aside for the use of the prophet Elijah. Elijah is said to be a witness at all circumcisions when the sign of the covenant is placed upon the body of the child. This custom stems from the incident at Mount Horeb (1 Kings 19): Elijah had arrived at Mount Horeb after the demonstration of God's presence and power on Mount Carmel. (1 Kings 18) God asks Elijah to explain his arrival, and Elijah replies: “I have been very jealous for the Lord, the God of hosts; for the people of Israel have forsaken thy covenant, thrown down thy altars, and slain thy prophets with the sword; and I, even I only, am left; and they seek my life, to take it away” (1 Kings 19:10). According to Rabbinic tradition, Elijah's words were patently untrue (1 Kings 18:4 and 1 Kings 19:18), and since Elijah accused Israel of failing to uphold the covenant, God would require Elijah to be present at every covenant of circumcision.

see also http:[//www.jewishanswers.org/](http://www.jewishanswers.org/ask-the-rabbi-category/the-jewish-calendar-and-holidays/passover/page/4/?p=1178).

Comment: Is an expression rooted in a literal image necessarily relegated to a literal application? In each of the examples you offer, the "empty chair" points, metaphorically I suggest, to a missing person.

Answer (score 1):

> TV debates: broadcasters will '*empty chair*' leaders who refuse to take
>   part.

The definition of *[metaphor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/metaphor)* suggests the expression *empty chair* is offered as a metaphor:

> noun
>
> 1 A figure of speech in which a word or phrase is applied to an object
>   or action to which it is not literally applicable:

In the expression *[Chairing the Member](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humours_of_an_Election)* of William Hogarth's famous cartoon (1755), sitting a victorious politician in an *chair* could be a **literal** application of the word, even though it seems to extend the phrase into a metaphorical realm of *celebration* and *honor*. The author of *[this recent article](http://www.theguardian.com/media/2015/jan/23/tv-debates-broadcasters-will-empty-chair-leaders-who-refuse-to-take-part)* reinforces his metaphorical intent by using apostrophes to suggest the literal 'empty chair' is making a metaphorical point along the lines of:

> TV debates: broadcasters will **disgrace** leaders who refuse to take
>   part

We can debate the exact word or phrase that should be used to **define** the verb phrase *empty chair*, because it is an idiomatic one-off expression in a complex context, but *empty chair* seems to point to something that is beyond the chair itself.

Evidence of this metaphorical intent is found in the fact that the journalists would not even need to place an empty chair on the stage to make their point. Of course, putting an empty chair on the stage would empower the imagery, but the moderator of the debates could simply use the verbal neologism to reveal the politician's absence, and the point will have been made quite explicitly:

> Tonight we have *empty chaired* Mr. Politician, who has refused to
>   participate in our debate forum. We believe he should participate, and
>   his absence speaks volumes to us. Exactly where his empty chair is
>   tonight may be one of the questions our debaters discuss.

Since the word *[chair](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chair)* already has several similar metaphorical applications, this extension of the word's meaning seems quite straightforward:

> NOUN
>
> 2.0 The person in charge of a meeting or of an organization (used as a neutral alternative to chairman or chairwoman):
>
> 2.1 The post of a chairperson:
>
> 3.0 A professorship:
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1.0 Act as chairperson of or preside over (an organization, meeting, or public event):
>
> 2.0 British Carry (someone) aloft in a chair or in a sitting position to celebrate a victory:

*Chair* is already a metonym for a *position of power and influence*, so *empty chair* is easily turned into a metonym of *abdicated power or influence*.

---

OED

en.wikipedia.org

www.theguardian.com